# How to retrieve id of objects from Firebase and store each one?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic5

I am writing an Ionic app with the the angular framework where I need to remove objects from Firebase real time database, and to do this I need the id of each object. Also I am an absolute beginner with all of this, so even looking through similar questions I was not able to find something that worked for me. Below is the code.

```
 import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';//as db

 getData(){

this.db.list('videos/images').valueChanges().subscribe(
data => {
  
  this.images = data.reverse();
}
```

)
}

how can I also get the id for each object and store it in the images array?

Comment: Please share an example of your database and the exact data you're trying to extract

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to solve this one, using snapshotChanges() insead of valueChanges()

```
getData(){
//console.log( this.selectedTag)
// getting data from fb, providing path 
this.db.list('videos/images').snapshotChanges().subscribe(
data => {  
  var j = JSON.stringify(data);
  var personObject = JSON.parse(j); 

  for (var item of personObject) {
      this.images.push({time:item.payload.time,tag:item.payload.tag,img:item.payload.img,key:item.key})
   }
   this.images = this.images.reverse()
}
```

)

images looks something like this,

```
images = [{time: someTime, tag: someTag, img: someImg, key: someKey},{...},{...}, ...]
```

So basically it pulls all my objects from the database and stores the object in the images array with the key value inside it. I then use the key to remove objects from the database, hope this helps someone with a similar problem.